# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObject' Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I was wondering why I can't add my data from Core Data to my tableview. It was first added and stored but when the app is reloaded the data is gone so I need to reload it but I can't seem to add the data to my tableview?
Here is the code

```
var titlename: [NSManagedObject] = []

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let manageContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Items")

    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try manageContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
            if let theName = result.value(forKey: "name") as? String {
                titlename.append(theName)
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to change titleName type to

```
 var titlename: [String] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

If tableview use `NSManagedObject` for create cell the simply add `NSManagedObject` data to the array.

```
for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
         titlename.append(result)
    }
```

OR

The tableview only use the string from `titlename` array for creating cell then just change the type `NSManagedObject` to `String`.

```
var titlename: [String] = []
```

This will help.